# How Type Casting Works in java?

Tags: java, casting, int, implicit-conversion, explicit

1. Why values of c are 2.0  and 2.5 although they have same data type
2. How is conversion taking place in a/b

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
           {
               int a = 5,b=2;
               float c;
               c=a/b;
               System.out.println(c);
               c=(float)a/b;
               System.out.println(c);
           }
   ```

Comment: Welcome back *Integer Division*.

Comment: `a` is an integer, `b` is an integer, so without explicit cast, the result will also be an integer

Comment: It's important to note that the type cast takes precedence over the `/` operator, so that `(float)a/b` is the same as `((float)a)/b`.  If you had written `(float)(a/b)` you would still get `2.0`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in understanding that despite declaring `c` as `float`, integer division still takes place with `a/b`.  Integer division in Java truncates any fractional part (so it can remain an `int`).  Only then is it implicitly converted to a `float` upon assignment to `c`, and `2.0` is printed.

The cast to a `float` in `(float)a/b` changes `a` to `5.0f` and forces floating point division before the result is assigned to `c`, so the correct result `2.5` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement, `a/b` is calculated.  As both variables are integers, the result is an integer too: `2`.  In your second statement, `a` is first converted to a `float` and then divided by `b`.  As one of the values is a `float`, the result is a `float` too: `2.5`.

Answer (score 0):

The first division is int / int --> int result.
the second is Float / int, --> Float results.